Airflow Random Failure
We have a Airflow job thats sends a lot of messages (>100k) to SQS.
The job mostly works perfectly but once in a while it fails for no reason.
When retriggered, it succeeds automatically (despite no change in underlying code).
Error message: airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed. The command returned a non-zero exit code 1.
Is there a solution to resolve such random failures?
